# Why is it not possible to print a hash directly in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, hash

Why is it not possible to print a hash directly.

```
p {:First=>1, :Second=>2}
```

> syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting '}'

But its possible to save it to a variable and then print that variable?

```
my_hash = {:First=>1, :Second=>2}
p my_hash
```

> {:First=>1, :Second=>2}

Comment: This is a duplicate, although I cannot find it at the moment. The short answer is: because Ruby thinks it's a block, add parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that it's because Ruby is confused and thinks you're passing a block to the `p` method.

```
p {:First=>1, :Second=>2}
SyntaxError: unexpected =>, expecting '}'
```

As you can see from the error, it was expecting a `}` where your hash rocket for the first key is. As you've already found out, you can set this as a variable and it works. But you can also pass the hash to the `p` method without setting it as a variable if you use parenthesis, because `p`, `puts` and `print` are just methods too. This works, because passing a block to a method in Ruby requires it to be outside of the parenthesis which then cuts down on the ambiguity of what you're trying to do.

```
p({:First=>1, :Second=>2})
{:First=>1, :Second=>2}
#=> {:First=>1, :Second=>2}
```

As noted by tadman in the comments, you can also omit the parenthesis and curly braces as Ruby knows that key/value pairs passed as arguments to a method are the equivalent to passing a hash and wouldn't be misinterpreted as a block.

```
p :First => 1, :Second => 2
{:First=>1, :Second=>2}
#=> {:First=>1, :Second=>2}
```

Comment: Also if you're using regular brackets you can omit braces: `p{:first => 1, :second => 2)` or `p(first: 1, second: 2)` using new notation.